I have electron fuse with backend but it is opening command prompt when i start my electron app and doesnot fetch data at first when electron is open
const runDjangoServer = async () => {



-----------------------------------------------------------------
  if (isDev) {

    const exeFile = path.join(__dirname, "../../runserver/runserver.exe");
    return exec(exeFile, function (err, data) {});
  }

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 else {
    const exeFile = path.join(process.resourcesPath, "/server/runserver.exe");
    return exec(exeFile, function (err, data) {});
  }
==============================================================================
};


I want to not open the command prompt when i open electron app and load my data when electron is open

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
